# How to Create an Instance of Model A, from a Form inside a view for Model B

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

So I have a `Message` model, and a `ChatRoom` model.

When I display a chat room, I use the `show` action on the ChatRoom controller.  In the view for this action, there is a little form for the user to create a post, and submit that post to the chat room being shown.

When I run my tests, however, I get an error "no route matches [POST] /messages/an_id_of_some_sort".  Specifically, in this little test:

```
post message_path, params: {message: {body: "yo ho ho and a bottle of rum!"}}
assert_redirected_to chat_room_path(@channel)
```

the error pops up in the `post message_path`.

The `show` method on the chat room controller looks like

```
def show

if(@user = current_user)
  @chats = @user.chat_rooms
  @chosen = ChatRoom.find_by(id: params[:id])

  if(@chosen.messages.any?)
    @messages = @chosen.messages

  else
    @messages = nil
  end

  @message = Message.new

end

end
```

Then the little form bit of the view is:

```
<div class="message-input">
    <%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Write Message..." %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :room, :value => params[:room] %>

      <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "message-submit-btn", name: "commit", value: "") do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>
      <% end %>

    <% end %>
  </div>
```

I have a `create` action on the Messages Controller which does the saving to the database:

```
@message = current_user.messages.build(message_params);
@message.chat_room = params[:room]

if @message.save
  redirect_to chat_room_path(@message.chat_room)
end
```

and routing-wise I have

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root 'welcome#welcome'

get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
post '/signup', to: 'users#create'
get 'users/signup_success'

delete '/chat_rooms/leave/:id', to: 'chat_rooms#leave', as: 'current'

get 'welcome/welcome'

resources :users
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]    #Only providing an Edit route for this resource.
resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update]
resources :chat_rooms, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index]
resources :messages, only: [:create, :edit, :destroy]

end
```

I have tried playing around with explicitly setting the `:url` on the form_for, but no dice.  There is another question on this problem, but the solution there hasn't really helped.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: `"no route matches [POST] ..."` could we see your `routes.rb`?, is there just `resources :messages, only: [:create, :edit, :destroy]`?

Comment: aight sorry, I put only the messages bit there because I thought that was the only relevant part.  I'll edit the post now.

Comment: What is the test that's failing? What is the full backtrace of the error? Your `ChatRoomsController#show` action contains a dodgy `if` statement, by the way -- you're always overriding the value of `@message`, regardless.

Comment: @TomLord thanks, I've added the bit of the test that fails.  Also, what's wrong with the `if` statement?  I might be being dim here but I can't see any problems with it.

Comment: Also, FYI, the ID it has in the url is the ID of the current chat room.

Comment: @Makcheese My point is that you're setting `@messages = @chosen.messages` or `@messages = nil`, but this is totally pointless sine you are then setting `@message = Message.new` and aren't actually using the `@messages` variable anywhere.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am using the `@messages` variable, in an unrelated part of the view.

Comment: Hmm, ok... Anyway, I digress..... Should that not just be `post :create, messages_path` instead of `post :create, message_path`?

Comment: yeah, you bringing up this confusion has led me to rename the `@message` variable so it's less confusing.  Also I'm going to see if I can ingeneral clean up the view.  If the solution IS to as simple as `messages_path` rather than `message_path`, I will be really angry at myself -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line you're running POST /messages/:id

```
post message_path, params: {message: {body: "yo ho ho and a bottle of rum!"}}
```

In your routes file you have this:

```
resources :messages, only: [:create, :edit, :destroy]
```

This will create the routes POST /messages, PUT/PATCH /messages/:id, and DELETE /messages/:id. You can verify this with `rake routes`.

None of these generated routes handle POST /messages/:id.

If you're trying to have the test create a new message, then you can use `messages_path` instead. `message_path` (with singular `message`) takes a message argument as a message, e.g. `message_path(Message.first)` and uses that to build the url.